# ¿Cual es la diferencia de hacer un script y llamar a uno?

Tags: javascript, html

En pocas palabras quiero saber cual es la diferencia, **PROS** y/o **CONTRAS** de tener un `script` lleno de `funciones`, o de llamar un archivo `.js` que contenga todas las funciones.

Hasta el momento no e tenido problemas creando archivos `.js` que dispongan de todas las funciones a utilizar, aparte de poder usarlas en distintas paginas `HTML` pero aparte de esto, ¿de que otra manera puede afectar esta diferencia?.

¿Esto aumenta el proceso de carga de la pagina o es solo un especie de buena practica de programación?.

Comment: Diferencia ninguna, funcionalmente es lo mismo, pero en cuanto a beneficios: Legibilidad de código, mejor mantenimiento y seguimiento, usabilidad para más de un archivo .html y/o .js, separación de funcionalidad

Comment: osea da lo mismo si pongo 1000 lineas de código de puras funciones en la pagina html?

Comment: @Lixus añadiendo un poco de detalle, eso sería una buena respuesta ;)

Comment: @felipeandrade "da lo mismo" funcionalmente, pero tiene inconvenientes inconvenientes graves (más tiempo de carga, menos usabilidad, etc) como te indicaba Lixus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pros:

- **Misma funcionalidad**: Funcionalmente va a ser lo mismo que tener el código en un .js e incluirlo en la página.
- **Código "personalizado"**: estarías cargando sólo el código que necesitas en cada página. Si tu página sólo usa una función, no quieres incluir un fichero con 1.000 funciones (aunque este pro se pierde al realizar caché los navegadores).
- **Menos conexiones**: Una conexión http menos; los navegadores tienen un límite de conexiones simultáneas, ahorrarte una va a hacer que tu página se cargue más rápido (aunque este pro se pierde al realizar caché los navegadores).

---

### Contras:

- **Legibilidad**: aunque ordenes bien el código, va a ser tedioso pasar líneas y líneas de JS y HTML (mezclas dos lenguajes diferentes)
- **Separación de interfaz y lógica de negocio**: relacionado con el punto anterior. Es mejor si el código se separa siguiendo el patrón de arquitectura MVC (modelo-vista-controlador), que va a llevar a los dos puntos siguientes.
- **Reutilización/Duplicidad**: al estar el código directamente en el HTML, esas funciones no pueden ser llamadas desde otra página HTML; mientras que si tuvieras un .js podrías incluirlo en varias HTML.
- **Mantenimiento**: relacionado con el anterior, a no ser que el JS inline se añade a través de un script en el servidor (p.e. incluyéndolo con PHP), entonces te vas a encontrar que tienes JavaScript en múltiples ficheros (incluso repetido) haciendo más difícil hacer cambios.
- **Rendimiento**: éste es el punto más importante, porque tener el JS embebido en la página afecta al rendimiento de varios modos:

  - **Descarga más lenta**: la página va a tener más líneas de código, va a pesar más KB por lo que va a tardar más en descargarse.
  - **Descarga innecesaria**: si tuvieses el código en un .js, el navegador podría guardar ese archivo en la caché y no necesitaría recargarlo la siguiente vez que se pida.
  - **Velocidad**: la ejecución del script "bloquea" el procesamiento de la página en el navegador, si tuvieras los scripts externos, podrías usar `defer`/`async` que sólo funcionan cuando el atributo `src` está presente.

---

La idea es que los contras de tener el código embebido directamente en la página hacen que los pros (que son pocos y no realmente fuertes) se vean insuficientes.

Answer (score 4):

Hay al menos dos motivos para no poner las funciones directamente en el HTML:

1. **Rendimiento en la carga de la web**:
   Si tienes una página web que se actualiza a cada llamada (o cada X tiempo) porque se genera dinámicamente (PHP o JSP o ASP o tecnologías similares), no es cacheable. Tendrás que descargarte las líneas de código y el HTML cada vez que quieras ver la página. Si además las funciones que usas no son únicamente específicas de esa página y las quieres reusar según vas navegando por tu aplicación, en cada carga de nuevo tendrás que descargarlas. En cambio, teniendo un fichero "estático" con todo ese código, el navegador puede cachearlo y te ahorras la carga.
2. **Claridad**: Cuando escribimos código, casi siempre acabamos usando un patrón del tipo MVC (modelo, vista y controlador), separando nuestra aplicación en capas. Si nos centramos en nuestra vista en formato web, podemos volver a dividirla en tres capas similares:

   - Modelo: el HTML (qué se ve).
   - Vista: Ficheros CSS (cómo se ve).
   - Controlador: Ficheros Javascript (cómo se comporta nuestra aplicación).

El mantenimiento del código es más sencillo así puesto que un diseñador podría encargarse de los CSS en cuanto le demos el HTML y el libro de estilo de la aplicación mientras que  un desarrollador front-end podría escribir las llamadas necesarias a back-end en un fichero sin tener que tratar con el código back-end (conociendo sólo el API). Además depurar el código es mucho más cómodo así.

Yo evitaría además cosas como

```
<tagname onclick=...>
```

Añadiendo siempre el comportamiento enteramente en el fichero js:

```
$('tagname').click(....);
```